# Change toolbar items visibility or text size

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a bottom `TabbedPage` that always worked the way I wanted, but with the update of the Xamarin.Forms to version 4.7, the items are showing the title, thus breaking the layout.

I would like to know a way to go back to the way it was before or decrease the size of the title.

I've tried other solutions that are here at Stack Overflow, but without success.

**Before Xamarin.Forms update:**

[image]

**After Xamarin.Forms update:**

[image]

**TabbedPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"       
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:home="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views.Home"
            xmlns:pdv="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views.Pdv"
            xmlns:historico="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views.Historico"
            xmlns:notificacoes="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views.Notificacao"
            xmlns:config="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views.Configuracao"
            xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions"
            x:Class="BaseApp.Views.TabbedPage.TabbedPage"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="{StaticResource CorItemBarra}"
            BarTextColor="{StaticResource CorBranco}"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource CorBranco}"            
            BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource CorPretoBarra}"        
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <NavigationPage Title="INÍCIO" IconImageSource="{StaticResource ImagemIconeHome}">
        <x:Arguments>
            <home:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <pdv:Pdv Title="PDVs" IconImageSource="{StaticResource ImagemIconePdv}" />
    <historico:Historico Title="HISTÓRICO" IconImageSource="{StaticResource ImagemIconeHistorico}" />
    <notificacoes:Notificacao Title="NOTIFICAÇÕES"
                              IconImageSource="{StaticResource ImagemIconeNotification}"
                              plugin:TabBadge.BadgeColor="Red"
                              plugin:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionTopRight"
                              plugin:TabBadge.BadgeTextColor="White" />
    <config:Configuracoes Title="CONFIGURAÇÕES" IconImageSource="{StaticResource ImagemIconeConfig}" />    
</TabbedPage>
```

**TabbedPage.xaml.cs**

```
using BaseApp.Services;
using BaseApp.Util;
using Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BaseApp.Views.TabbedPage
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TabbedPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {
        public TabbedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessageHome>(this, "AddItemTabbedPageRota", message =>
            {
                var pages = Children.GetEnumerator();
                pages.MoveNext(); // First page
                pages.MoveNext(); // Second page
                CurrentPage = pages.Current;
            });
                       
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessageDateHora>(this, "AddItemInformeValidaData", async message =>
                   {
                     DateTime result = await ValidaDataEHora.ObterDataAsync();

                       //if (Convert.ToBoolean(Application.Current.Properties["UserDataEHoraErrada"]) == true)
                       //    throw new TaskCanceledException(teste);

                     if (result != null)
                         Funcoes.ComparaData(result);
                 });

            // Adiciona o número de notificações que não foram visualizadas
            if (Sessao.QuantidadeNotificacoesNaoLidas > 0)
            {
                Page telaNotificacao = Children.FirstOrDefault(page => page is Notificacao.Notificacao);
                TabBadge.SetBadgeText(telaNotificacao, Sessao.QuantidadeNotificacoesNaoLidas.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example? The default behavior of TabbedPage is showing the icon and title at the same time no matter what version of Xamarin.forms is. Are you using any third-part library?

Comment: I'm using the library to show the notification counter badge, it's called `Plugin.Badge` and I edited the question with the new informations. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Still need a Minimal, Reproducible Example as I can't achieve the result in first screenshot with TabbedPage.

Comment: I didn't understand. What else do I need to post?

Comment: When I use Xamarin.forms which version is lower than 4.7, the TabbedPage works the same as the second screenshot instead of the first screenshot.